# insert value in a column from an existing column

Tags: sql

I've gone through all the solutions provide in others' questions asked, still my code isn't working!

I have added a column `member_name` to the already existing table `instalment`, and now I want to insert values in it from an existing table.

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
update instalment
    set member_name = select member_name
                      from member
                        inner join instalment on instalment.member_no = member.member_no
```

But somehow it is giving me an error for syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The select must be done in a sub-query:

```
update instalment
    set member_name = (select member_name
                       from "member"
                       where instalment.member_no = member_no)
```

**Note 1**: in ANSI SQL `member` is a reserved word, that's why it's double-quoted as `"member"`.

**Note 2**: Why copy names? Just risk of data inconsistency. Keep a name only in one place, JOIN when needed (or create a view).

Comment: yea , that's why I didn't add it earlier . But since I'm working with php as well so I made things simpler for php :P

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE instalment SET member_name = T2.member_name 
FROM instalment T1 INNER JOIN member T2 ON T1.member_no = T2.member_no
```

Comment: I think it will give an error. You can't specify target table ' instalment' for update in FROM clause .

Comment: Check it out.......... its tested, its an alternative answer, better go with above answer.

Comment: Please specify dbms, since this is non ANSI SQL. (And no dbms specified in question.)